# How can I access the Nether on the Xbox 360 Minecraft on a superflat world?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Is it possible to access the Nether on a superflat world on the Xbox 360 edition of Minecraft?

I have enabled the "structures" option but this only seems to generate buildings with at best a crafting table, I haven't seen any bonus chests or "blacksmith" houses.

Is it just not possible on the Xbox 360 edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can imagine, it would only be possible in creative mode as you need obsidian to build a Nether portal, which super flat lands on 360 seem to lack. The only thing I could tell you to do is to build a nether portal in creative mode, save, switch over to survival mode, then enter the portal. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you enabled structures, you can include a stronghold and take the lava from there plus water from the fountains and get obsidian that way.  Rather than mine the obsidian, you can pour the lava (carefully) and then quickly pour water on the source block to make it obsidian.  Do this until you get a portal shape. If you can’t get access to flint from gravel, then keep at least one bucket of the lava.  Create a pool out of dirt or cobblestone right next to the portal and pour in the lava.  then place something that burns like a block of wood or leaves on the other side of the portal and then wait for the lava to catch the material on fire and that should light the portal